# Is there a way to pass values from a Quartz Job to an MVC Controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, quartz.net

I'm working on an .NET application which uses Quartz in order to schedule a certain DAL function to run once every 10 seconds. The DAL function (CheckIncompleteExists) returns an object, in which we retrieve an integer from (TransacID).

**Job**

```
    {
        TransactionDAL transactionContext = new TransactionDAL();
        public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("--> Database check completed");
            if (transactionContext.CheckIncompleteExists() != null)
            {
                return Task.FromResult<int>(transactionContext.CheckIncompleteExists().TransacID);
            }
            return Task.FromResult<int>(0);
        }
    }
```

**Scheduler**

```
public class JobScheduler
    {
        public static void Start()
        {
            Task<IScheduler> schedulerjob = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
            IScheduler scheduler = schedulerjob.Result;
            scheduler.Start();

            IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<Incompletescanjob>().Build();
            //trigger the job
            ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
            .StartNow()
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
            .WithIntervalInSeconds(10) //run the method every 10 second
             .RepeatForever())
                .Build();

            scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
        }
}
```

The Job and Scheduler works fine and is able to return the correct value. What I want to do is be able to pass the integer value from the Job into a controller, HomeController, for use in other controller functions.
How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

If this value is shared among all the users of the system then you could declare a static variable and assign the value to that variable. This variable can be accessed from anywhere in the application.

Otherwise consider use of sessions for each users.